# com.diffplug.gradle.spotless && task clean(type: Delete){} Error:Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, gradle-plugin

This my `build.gradle`

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        ...
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.2'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
        classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigationVersion"
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

plugins {
    id "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless" version "3.26.0"
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}

spotless {
    kotlin {
        target "**/*.kt"
        ktlint(ktlintVersion).userData(['max_line_length' : '100'])
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

The original compilation was successful, but when the `spotless` was introduced, it caused this error:

> ```
> com.diffplug.gradle.spotless && task clean(type: Delete){} Error:Cannot add task 'clean' as a task with that name already exists
> ```

So, I guess these two parts are conflicting, but I don’t know the specific reasons.

```
plugins {
    id "com.diffplug.gradle.spotless" version "3.26.0"
}
//...
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding to R.Desai's answer,

actually Gradle's BasePlugin cleans only app level build directory. The doc says

> clean — Delete Deletes the build directory and everything in it, i.e.
> the path specified by the Project.getBuildDir() project property.

[Check the docs here for more info](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/base_plugin.html).

However, the solution is the same. The spotless plugin is conflicting with your defined "clean" task as it has the same implementation of it under the hood, which cleans the project level build directory. This has been issues in their github repo ["Duplicate clean task #521"](https://github.com/diffplug/spotless/issues/521)